# MongoDB schema schedule publish

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to do a post publication routine every 10 minutes of data obtained by API.

The routine of cron and others works perfectly, but the problem comes when I try to get the first article with a date closer to expiration and has not been published or as little as possible.

I have tried to create an incremental field with the times that has been published, update the date of publication, etc; But I can not give with the formula, I always return the same result, the same article.

Schema

```
"_id": item.ID,
"title": item.title,
"images": [ item.firstImage ],
"url": "none",
"expired": "2017-04-30T22:00:00+03:00",
"lastPublish": "2017-04-30T20:41:02+03:00",
"publish": 0
```

Code

```
db.find({}).sort({ 'expired': 1, 'lastPublish': 1 }).limit(1).exec(function(err, doc) {
//db.find({}).sort({ 'publish': 1, 'expired': 1 }).limit(1).exec(function(err, doc) {

    db.update({ '_id': doc._id }, { '$set': { 'lastPublish': new Date(), '$inc': { 'publish': 1 } })

});
```

I need to make a sort of circular queue, post those that expire earlier (they have dates of hours and days of difference) and when it's over, start over. But I always publish the first post and I'm running out of ideas.

I'd better leave for a few hours and retake it later, when I've cleared my mind.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Running the following routine works properly, I don't know why yesterday didn't work, apart from the one that was missing to choose the element of the array ([0]).

```
db.find({}).sort({ 'publish': 1, 'expired': 1 }).limit(1).exec(function(err, doc) {

    db.update({ '_id': doc[0]._id }, { '$inc': { 'publish': 1 }, '$set': { 'lastPublish': new Date() } });
```

thanks !